# Local minima of a trivial sin(x) function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

The paper on which it came had $4$ choices of answer, out of which $2$ options are creating confusion.

> For the function $f(x) = sin(x)$ in the interval $x\in[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}]$, the number and location(s) of the **local minima** of the function is(are) ?
>
> $i)\ \ 1\ at\ \frac{3\pi}{2}$
>
> $ii)\ \ 2\ at\ \frac{\pi}{4} and\frac{3\pi}{2}$

According to me option $(ii)$ should be the right choice. But I'm not sure. Can anyone help ?

[image]

Comment: It seems that the picture is labelled slightly wrong. But yes, I would say that option II is a good one.

Comment: Oh yes. In the image the $2^{nd}$ local minimum should be labeled as $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, not $\frac{7\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a local minima as being a point on the graph where you can draw an arbitrarily small circle around the point and every point in the graph that is in the circle will be larger than the proposed minima. In the case where a minima is an end point, all that we examine is the side of the graph inside the interval we care about. The main idea here is that an endpoint can be a local extrema.

So $\pi/4$ and $3\pi/2$ give us our two local minima.

Comment: Yes, option $(ii)$ was my initial choice. But they (the paper setter) are saying the correct option is $(i)$. But they have not given any explanation. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Is the interval perhaps open? If the interval is open, then the left endpoint is not a local min, since it is not in the interval. But if the interval is closed at $\pi/4$, then I would certainly say there is a local min there.

Comment: The interval is certainly closed. May be they are applying the logic of differentiability to find the max/min. That is the function $f(x)$ will have a max/min at point $a$, if $f'(a) = 0$. Now since $f(x)$ is defined only when $x\in[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}]$, so it's not differentiable at $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$. What do you think ?

Comment: A reasonable explanation. Not quite correct on their part, but that may be what they are thinking.